# Make flex child element occupy 100% height of parent flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container flex with content flexes. How do i make content flex occupy full width and height of container flex.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="main-nav">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</div>

#main{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
}
#main-nav{
    width: 100%
    height: 50px; 
}
.container{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex: 1;
}
.content{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

The above code makes content to occupy 100% width of container but height is based on the text within the content. I tried the solutions mentioned from similar questions but had no luck and it was still the same.

Basically, I want each of the content to occupy the same height as occupied by the container in the viewport height. I also tried jQuery,

```
var rht = $("#container").height();
$(".content").height(rht);
```

It changes the height properly but adds a horizontal scroll bar with increase in width.

Comment: doesn't the answer below solve this issue..?

Answer (score 2):

After several updates to the original question:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: borderbox;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#main-nav {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o3oz0c9e/)

Comment: Please find the updated code. That is my actual case. Am I going wrong anywhere?

Comment: Updated again. it takes full viewport height.

Comment: So sorry for so many edits. I want to make contents occupy full width and height of container flex with one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set width or height of flex's child is bigger (size of flex)/(number of flex's childs) but you can add `position: absolute` into `.content` and `position: relative` into `.container` then set `width` and `height` for `.content`. First `.content` is under second `.content`, you can use propety `z-index` or `display: none` to control.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: borderbox;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#main-nav {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">left</div>
    <div class="content">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```